# Object doesn't seems to collide using AABB collision method

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection, aabb

I am new to opengl. I am doing a simple 2D shooting game and using AABB collision to do collision between objects and bullet. I do the collision for my plane and the square but it doesn't seems to work. Can help me check what's my problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

#define SPACEBAR 32

class Plane {
public:
    GLfloat x = 0.05f;
    GLfloat y = 0.95f;
    GLfloat width = 0.05f;
    GLfloat height = 0.10f;
    GLfloat moveX = 0.0f;
    GLfloat moveY = 0.0f;

    void drawPlane(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);
};

class Enemy {
public:
    GLfloat x, y;
    GLfloat width, height;
    GLfloat sqrMoveX, sqrMoveY;

    void drawEnemySqr(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);
};

Plane plane;
Enemy enemy;

GLfloat XMax, XMin, YMax, YMin;
GLdouble clipAreaXLeft, clipAreaXRight, clipAreaYBottom, clipAreaYTop;

int refreshMills = 30;

float RandomNumberX() {
    float Min = -1.0f;
    float Max = 1.0f;

    return ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
}

float RandomNumberY() {
    float Min = 0.7f;
    float Max = 1.0f;

    return ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
}

void Timer(int value) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(refreshMills, Timer, 0);
}

bool collision(GLfloat x1, GLfloat y1, GLfloat w1, GLfloat h1, 
               GLfloat x2, GLfloat y2, GLfloat w2, GLfloat h2) {
    if ((x1 < (x2 + w2)) && 
        ((x1 + w1) > x2) && 
        (y1 < (y2 + h2)) && 
        ((h1 + y1) > y2)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void initGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void Plane :: drawPlane(GLfloat planeX, GLfloat planeY, GLfloat planeWidth, GLfloat planeHeight) {
    glTranslatef(moveX, moveY, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-(planeX), -(planeY));
    glVertex2f(planeX, -(planeY));
    glVertex2f(planeX + planeWidth, -(planeY - planeHeight));
    glVertex2f(planeX - (planeWidth), -(planeY - (planeHeight + 0.20f)));
    glVertex2f(-(planeX + planeWidth), -(planeY - planeHeight));
    glEnd();

    if (moveX > XMax) {
        moveX = XMax;
    }
    else if (moveX < XMin) {
        moveX = XMin;
    }
    if (moveY > YMax) {
        moveY = YMax;
    }
    else if (moveY < YMin) {
        moveY = YMin;
    }
}

void Enemy :: drawEnemySqr(GLfloat enemyX, GLfloat enemyY, GLfloat enemyWidth, GLfloat enemyHeight) {
    glTranslatef(sqrMoveX, sqrMoveY, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(enemyX, enemyY);
    glVertex2f(enemyX + enemyWidth, enemyY);
    glVertex2f(enemyX + enemyWidth, enemyY + enemyHeight);
    glVertex2f(enemyX, enemyWidth + enemyY);
    glEnd();

    sqrMoveY -= 0.0005f;

    if (sqrMoveY < -1.8f) {
        sqrMoveX = RandomNumberX();
        sqrMoveY = RandomNumberY();
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushMatrix();
    plane.drawPlane(plane.x, plane.y, plane.width, plane.height);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    enemy.drawEnemySqr(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    glPopMatrix();

    if (collision(plane.moveX, plane.moveY, plane.width, plane.height, 
                  enemy.sqrMoveX, enemy.sqrMoveY, enemy.width, enemy.height) == true) {
        enemy.sqrMoveY = -2.0f;
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyButton(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        plane.moveX += 0.05f;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        plane.moveX += -0.05f;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        plane.moveY += 0.05f;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        plane.moveY += -0.05f;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(480, 640);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("Plane Shooting Game");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(25, Timer, 0);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyButton);
    initGL();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your `collision` needs more extensive tests. At a glance, it seems to test only if object #1 is entirely inside object #2.

Comment: Ya, I do need more testing as the collision is not perfect yet with this function. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in this line:

```
if (collision(plane.moveX, plane.moveY, plane.width, plane.height, 
              enemy.sqrMoveX, enemy.sqrMoveY, enemy.width, enemy.height) == true)
```

You must pass `plane.x`, `plane.y`, `enemy.x`, `enemy.y` to collision function instead of `plane.moveX`, `plane.moveY`, `enemy.sqrMoveX`, `enemy.sqrMoveY`.

Comment: It works! I changed the x and y coordinate of my plane to 0.0f and changed the variable input of collision function in display function to plane.x + plane.moveX and plane.y + plane.moveY. Then the collision works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should except this guys answer